# Bigquery: search multiple tables and aggregate with first_seen and last_seen

Tags: mysql, sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a Bigquery database with multiple tables:

```
table1
    id,timestamp,data
    1,1428969600,AAAAA
    2,1428969600,CCCCC
    [..]
    20,1428969600,ZZZZZ

table2
    id,timestamp,data
    1,1429056000,AAAAA
    2,1429056000,BBBBB
    3,1429056000,CCCCC
    [..]
    20,1429056000,ZZZZZ

table3
    id,timestamp,data
    1,1429142400,AAAAA
    2,1429142400,BBBBB
    3,1429142400,CCCCC
    [..]
    20,1429142400,ZZZZZ
```

I want to run a search over all the tables (table1, table2 and table3) to see when the value in the field "data" first and last appeared and take the associated field "timestamp".

This should be the result:

```
id,timestamp_first, timestamp_last,data
1,1428969600,1429142400,AAAAA
2,1429056000,1429142400,BBBBB
3,1428969600,1429142400,CCCCC
[..]
20,1428969600,1429142400,ZZZZZ
```

Can someone give me some tips how I can make a search like this?

Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first union the tables (in BigQuery the syntax for union is comma). Then there are two approaches:

1. Use analytic functions FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE.

```
SELECT id, timestamp_first, timestamp_last, data FROM
(SELECT 
  id,
  timestamp,
  FIRST_VALUE(timestamp) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY timestamp ASC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
  AS timestamp_first,
  LAST_VALUE(timestamp) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY timestamp ASC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
  AS timestamp_last
FROM table1, table2, table3
```

2. Use aggregation MIN/MAX on timestamp to find first/last and then join back to the same tables.

```
SELECT a.id id, timestamp_first, timestamp_last, data FROM
(SELECT id, data FROM table1,table2,table3) a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
   id, 
   MIN(timestamp) timestamp_first,
   MAX(timestamp) timestamp_last 
 FROM table1,table2,table3 GROUP BY id) b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and correct answer! Just a detail: To work in Bigquery I had to add the projectid to the table: (SELECT id, data FROM project.table1,project.table2,project.table3)

Comment: Do you have probably also a example for the first approach?

Comment: OK, I sketched the first approach as well