# how to choose best row inside a partition when using GROUP BY

Tags: google-bigquery

In bigquery I want to be able to select a column that is not in the group by columns list, by applying a condition on another column.

say I have the following columns
`group, id, datecreated`

and the following query:
`select group, max(datecreated) from table group by group`

I want the query to also return the `id` of the row with the `max(datecreated)`

What I've come to understand until now is that Aggregate functions only apply over one column. An idea would be here to concatenate date created and `id`, get MAX(), and extract ID with a regular expression afterwards.
I feel like there should be an easier solution.

Comment: SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY datecreated DESC GROUP BY group LIMIT 1. The most recent date will be at the top.... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I need to be able to return first Row ordered by datecreated inside each group

Comment: then edit this in your question? The way it reads currently it does seem like you're looking for ONE ID from ONE group :). A sample input/desired output always helps for DB questions

Comment: Also you can check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681036/bigquery-search-multiple-tables-and-aggregate-with-first-seen-and-last-seen, it shows two alternative approaches. First similar to Pentium10 answer, but with use of FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Window Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions), partition by group, then order by time descending and choose the first one.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT g,
          v,
          row_number() over (partition BY g
                             ORDER BY t DESC) AS POSITION
   FROM
     (SELECT 1 AS g,
             1 AS t,
             10 AS v),
     (SELECT 1 AS g,
             2 AS t,
             20 AS v),
     (SELECT 1 AS g,
             3 AS t,
             15 AS v))
WHERE POSITION=1
```

for this small dataset this returns

```
+---+----+----------+---+
| g | v  | position |   |
+---+----+----------+---+
| 1 | 15 |        1 |   |
+---+----+----------+---+
```